# How to trigger a PHP Script with an Email?

Tags: php, web-services, email, automation, cron

**Goal:**

- on an incoming email, the system should call a php script.

**Problems:**

- dont do it with the help of cronjobs (because its kind of inefficient)
- [smtp2web](http://smtp2web.com) is (was) a web-service, that exactly seemed to handle that - but doesnt work no more (?)

so if you know web-services similar to smtp2web.com or some other strategy - please let everybody know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you on a linux box, setup an alias in the aliases file:

```
alias: "|/path/to/script/script.php"
```

The script will run whenever an email is sent to the alias@domain.com

The aliases file is in: /etc/

Comment: by now email handling is provided by an ISP - we dont use an own email server. Just called the ISP, but they arent able to configurate that individually. So an external web-service would be better. Thank you anyway for your quick response!

Comment: just found the great service i was looking for: [cloudmailin](https://cloudmailin.com) ... little disadvantage - its limited (200mails/month for free) - but works like charme!

Comment: Glad I could throw some light on it.